# Crossed physics bodies issue in cocos2dxv3.4

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, physics-engine

I am new to Cocos2dx v3.x.I am developing a basic car racing game in which the car can move within the continuous scrolling track which is straight and small curvy like "Road Fighter" game in Google play Store.For moving the car,i am using device accelerometer and adjusts the velocity of the car body acc. to that.For the path body,i am using EdgeChain Shape of 5 points which i have shown below so that it makes the bound area for the car motion and car should not go beyond that.But with setVelocity function,my car body goes outside the boundary.I have also set the CollisionBitmask and ContactTestBitmask,collision is detected,even then the physics body of car crossed over the edge chain body of path.

```
auto *sprite = Sprite::create("Road.jpg");
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2));
sprite->setScaleX(rX);
sprite->setScaleY(rY);
this->addChild(sprite, 0);

auto edge_body=PhysicsBody::createEdgeChain(vec ,5 ,PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT,3);
edge_body->setDynamic(false);
edge_body->addShape(PhysicsShapeEdgeChain::create(vec3, 5));
sprite->setPhysicsBody(edge_body);
edge_body->setCollisionBitmask(1);
edge_body->setContactTestBitmask(true);
//where vec and vec3 are vectors of 5 points acc to track boundary.


auto *mycar=Sprite::create(car_png_name);
mycar->setPosition(Point(winSize.width/2,winSize.height*0.35));
addChild(mycar,2);
mycar_body=PhysicsBody::createBox(mycar->getContentSize(),PhysicsMaterial(0,1,0));
mycar->setPhysicsBody(mycar_body);
mycar_body->setRotationEnable(false);
mycar_body->setCollisionBitmask(2);
mycar_body->setContactTestBitmask(true);


// DEVICE ACCELEROMETER
Device::setAccelerometerEnabled(true);
auto listener= EventListenerAcceleration::create (CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::OnAcceleration,this));
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);


auto contact_listener=EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();
contact_listener->onContactBegin=CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::onContactBegin, this);
this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(contact_listener, this);



void HelloWorld::OnAcceleration(cocos2d::Acceleration *acc, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
  #define KFILTERINGFACTOR 0.7
  #define KRESTACCELX 0
  #define KsquirrelMAXPOINTSPERSEC (winSize.width*0.5)
  #define KMAXDIFFX 0.15
   double rollingX=0;
    acc->y = acc->x;
    rollingX = (acc->y * KFILTERINGFACTOR) + (rollingX * (1.0 - KFILTERINGFACTOR));
    float accelX = acc->y - rollingX;
    float accelDiff = accelX - KRESTACCELX;
    float accelFraction = accelDiff / KMAXDIFFX;
    carspeed = KsquirrelMAXPOINTSPERSEC * accelFraction*1.5;

     if(mycar_body!=NULL)
    mycar_body->setVelocity(Vec2(carspeed*1.5,0));

}
```

I have faced this issue in Cocos2dxv3.4.The same logic works fine in Cocos2dxv2.2.6 with box2d b2body.I am not getting where i am wrong or how in other way,i can move my car with accelerometer within the scrolling boundary.Can anyone Suggest?

Thanks in advance.